# Vega-Lite (Deneb): Struggling to apply Min & Max Value on Line Chart AND text label and point at end of Line

Tags: json, powerbi, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, deneb

I'm lost in the Vega-lite sauce. Having trouble understanding where I'm going wrong.

I essentially need two layers:

- lines for all years ("color":)
- a single red line for the current year (2023)
- a mark to highlight: a) the highest point, b) the lowest point and c) the latest point on the same 2023 filtered line - with a text label showing the value (see image below)

[image]

I'm getting partial success but feel I'm coding things in the wrong order or wrong layer. The lowest temperature mark for 2023 isn't respecting the filter transform, and the text label is being effected by the "color": encoding instead of the one for the 2023 mark.

I've attached the pbix here: [TemperatureDEV_pbix](https://github.com/PBIQueryous/Deneb/blob/main/Dev/Temperature_DEV.pbix)
*(nb: this is a large dataset, I have toggled on the "override data limit" option)*

Apologies in advance for the JSON mess. For the highest and lowest marks I have tried to use "window": expression. In a separate attempt I was able to get the end mark using "argmax": but I wasn't able to combine both the end mark and the highest/lowest marks.

```json
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "DayOfYear",
      "type": "temporal",
      "axis": {
        "labels": false,
        "ticks": false,
        "grid": false,
        "title": "Day Of Year"
      }
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "Temp",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"zero": false},
      "title": "Temperature"
    },
    "color": {
      "legend": null,
      "field": "Year",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {
        "reverse": false,
        "range": [
          "#0041C2",
          "#0041C250",
          "#0041C230",
          "#4169E220",
          "#4863A015"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  
  "layer": [
    
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "line",
        "interpolate": "monotone",
        "strokeWidth": 1.5
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "calculate": "(datum.Temp)",
          "as": "2023_temp"
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "field": "Year",
            "oneOf": ["2023"]
          }
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "DayOfYear",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {
            "labels": false,
            "ticks": false,
            "grid": false,
            "title": "Day Of Year"
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "2023_temp",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"zero": false},
          "title": "Temperature"
        }
      },
      "layer": [
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "interpolate": "monotone",
            "stroke": "crimson",
            "strokeWidth": 3
          },
          "encoding": {
            "y": {"field": "2023_temp"}
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "left",
            "dx": 5,
            "size": 15,
            "fontWeight": "bold",
            "color": "red"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "x": {
              "aggregate": "max",
              "field": "DayOfYear"
            },
            "y": {
              "aggregate": {
                "argmax": "DayOfYear"
              },
              "field": "2023_temp"
            },
            "text": {
              "aggregate": {
                "argmax": "DayOfYear"
              },
              "field": "2023_temp",
              "format": ".3~s"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "window": [
            {"op": "rank", "as": "jeff"}
          ],
          "sort": [
            {
              "field": "Temp",
              "order": "descending"
            }
          ]
        },
        {"filter": "datum.jeff ==1"}
      ],
      "mark": {
        "type": "point",
        "shape": "triangle-down",
        "size": 200,
        "yOffset": -8,
        "fill": "red",
        "opacity": 1
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "DayOfYear"},
        "y": {"field": "Temp"}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "window": [
            {
              "op": "rank",
              "as": "tempRank"
            }
          ],
          "sort": [
            {
              "field": "Temp",
              "order": "ascending"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "filter": "datum.tempRank == 1"
        }
      ],
      "mark": {
        "type": "point",
        "shape": "circle",
        "size": 200,
        "yOffset": -8,
        "fill": "red",
        "opacity": 1,
        "stroke": null
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {"field": "DayOfYear"},
        "y": {"field": "Temp"}
      }
    },
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "transform": [
            {
              "calculate": "(datum.Temp)",
              "as": "1979_temp"
            },
            {
              "filter": "datum.Year == '1979'"
            }
          ],
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "interpolate": "monotone",
            "stroke": "orange",
            "strokeWidth": 3
          },
          "encoding": {
            "y": {"field": "1979_temp"}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this?

[image]

```
{
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "field": "DayOfYear",
      "type": "temporal",
      "axis": {
        "labels": false,
        "ticks": false,
        "grid": false,
        "title": "Day Of Year"
      }
    },
    "y": {
      "field": "Temp",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {"zero": false},
      "title": "Temperature"
    },
    "color": {
      "legend": null,
      "field": "Year",
      "type": "quantitative",
      "scale": {
        "reverse": false,
        "range": [
          "#0041C2",
          "#0041C250",
          "#0041C230",
          "#4169E220",
          "#4863A015"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "layer": [
    {
      "mark": {
        "type": "line",
        "interpolate": "monotone",
        "strokeWidth": 1.5
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "calculate": "(datum.Temp)",
          "as": "2023_temp"
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "field": "Year",
            "oneOf": ["2023"]
          }
        }
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "DayOfYear",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {
            "labels": false,
            "ticks": false,
            "grid": false,
            "title": "Day Of Year"
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "2023_temp",
          "type": "quantitative",
          "scale": {"zero": false},
          "title": "Temperature"
        }
      },
      "mark": {
        "type": "line",
        "interpolate": "monotone",
        "stroke": "crimson",
        "strokeWidth": 3
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "field": "Year",
            "oneOf": ["2023"]
          }
        },
        {
          "window": [
            {"op": "rank", "as": "high"}
          ],
          "sort": [
            {
              "field": "Temp",
              "order": "descending"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "window": [
            {"op": "rank", "as": "low"}
          ],
          "sort": [
            {
              "field": "Temp",
              "order": "ascending"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "window": [
            {"op": "rank", "as": "last"}
          ],
          "sort": [
            {
              "field": "Year",
              "order": "ascending"
            },
            {
              "field": "DayOfYear",
              "order": "descending"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "layer": [
              {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            
            "fontSize": {"expr": "datum.high ==1 || datum.low==1|| datum.last==1?10:0"
            },
            "dy":-25,
            "fill": "black",
            "yOffset": 0,
            "opacity": 1
          },
          "encoding": {
      "text": {"field": "Temp", "type": "quantitative"}
    }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "point",
            "shape": "circle",
            "size": {
              "expr": "datum.high ==1 || datum.low==1|| datum.last==1?150:0"
            },
            "yOffset": 0,
            "strokeWidth": 0.8,
            "stroke": "black",
            "fill": "red",
            "opacity": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "transform": [
            {
              "calculate": "(datum.Temp)",
              "as": "1979_temp"
            },
            {
              "filter": "datum.Year == '1979'"
            }
          ],
          "mark": {
            "type": "line",
            "interpolate": "monotone",
            "stroke": "orange",
            "strokeWidth": 3
          },
          "encoding": {
            "y": {"field": "1979_temp"}
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you @DavideBacci - for responding so swiftly and comprehensively - this is exactly what I was aiming for. For my understanding, are we effectively identifying the high/low marks, then "hiding" the points that don't match the high/low points?

Marked as answered and Thumbed Up.

I have related question for an alternative method where I also had partial success - I'll post a new question! (note: It's page 2 of the PBIX using ArgMax

Comment: Yes, that is effectively it. This is a common technique for just rendering the marks you want. Also, I removed some of your encodings - don't forget they bubble up and inherit a parent encoding if not is specified. It helps keep the spec smaller and easier to manage.

Comment: BTW, this is still unsolved at the moment if you can mark as solved. Thanks

Comment: Thanks @Davide - apologies for the unsolved oversight! I had tired eyes - you must get properly fed up of asking for people to mark the question as solved - forgive me!